# Add dummy data when no conditions are met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that returns a set with different clauses, this is the part I'm having a little problem with:

```
SELECT CASE             WHEN td.BSP <= 2    THEN '01-02'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 3    THEN '02-03'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 5    THEN '03-05'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 8    THEN '05-08'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 13   THEN '08-13'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 21   THEN '13-21'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 34   THEN '21-34'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 55   THEN '34-55'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 89   THEN '55-89'
                        WHEN td.BSP <= 1000 THEN '89-1000'
                END AS label
```

This is OK, and works like I want, however when there is no data for `BSP <=3` for example, it doesn't print that line, which is OK in all cases, except that I would like to have it, either with 0 or a dummy value. This is after as it gets picked by a pivot table in excel and excel only creates headers for available data. So I will need to have the line with the brackets I don't have data as well.

I'm adding here the complete statement:

```
DECLARE @RaceTrack CHAR(5)= 'Bala';
DECLARE @Category VARCHAR(4000)= 'All, Class, Days, Distance, Race, Runners, Total Bracket Count, Runners2';
DECLARE @TrotPace VARCHAR(10)= 'Excluded';
WITH CTE_TblData
     AS (SELECT td.EVENT_ID, 
                td.MENU_HINT, 
                SUBSTRING(td.menu_hint, 7, 4) AS [RaceTrack],
                td.EVENT_NAME, 
                td.BSP, 
                td.EVENT_DT AS Expr1003, 
                td.WIN_LOSE, 
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY event_id) AS [RaceRunners], 
                td.[Race No] AS RaceNo, 
                replace(LEFT(SUBSTRING(td.EVENT_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', td.EVENT_NAME) + 1, LEN(td.EVENT_NAME)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(td.EVENT_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', td.EVENT_NAME) + 2, LEN(td.EVENT_NAME)))), 'm', '') AS Distance, 
                REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(td.EVENT_NAME), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(td.EVENT_NAME)) - 1)) AS Class, 
                FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, td.EVENT_DT, 103), 'dddd') AS [Day], 
                DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, td.EVENT_DT, 103)) AS [DayNumber]
         FROM tblData td
         WHERE(@TrotPace <> 'Excluded' OR td.event_name NOT LIKE '%trot%' AND td.event_name NOT LIKE '%pace%') AND SUBSTRING(td.menu_hint, 7, 4) = @RaceTrack),
     NewCTE1_PriceLabel
     AS (SELECT td.*, price.label AS [PriceBracketLabel]
         FROM CTE_TblData AS td
              CROSS APPLY
         (
             SELECT CASE    WHEN td.BSP <= 2    THEN '01-02'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 3    THEN '02-03'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 5    THEN '03-05'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 8    THEN '05-08'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 13   THEN '08-13'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 21   THEN '13-21'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 34   THEN '21-34'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 55   THEN '34-55'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 89   THEN '55-89'
                            WHEN td.BSP <= 1000 THEN '89-1000'
                    END AS label
         ) AS price),
     NewCTE2_WindowedCount
     AS (SELECT *, 
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY event_id, 
                                           PriceBracketLabel) AS [PriceBracketRunners]
         FROM NewCTE1_PriceLabel),
     DataCube
     AS (SELECT td.event_id, 
                td.MENU_HINT, 
                td.EVENT_NAME, 
                td.Expr1003, 
                td.RaceNo, 
                td.Distance, 
                td.Class, 
                td.[Day], 
                CASE WHEN brackets.category = brackets2.category then  brackets.category ELSE  brackets.category  + ' : ' + brackets2.category END  AS bracket_category, 
                CASE WHEN brackets.label = brackets2.label THEN td.PriceBracketlabel + ' : ' + brackets.label ELSE td.PriceBracketlabel + ' : ' + brackets.label + ' : ' + brackets2.label END AS bracket_label, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN 1      ELSE 0 END) AS CountHorses_Winners, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN td.BSP ELSE 0 END) AS SumPrices_Winners, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 0 THEN 1      ELSE 0 END) AS CountHorses_Losers, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 0 THEN td.BSP ELSE 0 END) AS SumPrices_Losers
         FROM NewCTE2_WindowedCount AS td
              CROSS APPLY
         (
             SELECT 'All' AS category, 
                    'All' AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Runners' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.RaceRunners <= 7    THEN '01-07'
                        WHEN td.RaceRunners <= 12   THEN '07-12'
                        WHEN td.RaceRunners <= 1000 THEN '12-1000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Total Bracket Count' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.PriceBracketRunners = 1      THEN '01'
                        WHEN td.PriceBracketRunners IN(2, 3) THEN '02-03'
                        WHEN td.PriceBracketRunners > 3      THEN '04-1000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Distance' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.distance <= 1200  THEN '0-1200'
                        WHEN td.distance <= 1600  THEN '1200-1600'
                        WHEN td.distance <= 10000 THEN '1600-10000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Race' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.raceno < 5     THEN '0-4'
                        WHEN td.raceno < 1000  THEN '04-1000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             --the stuff after the "then" is the title for the column, the stuff inside the brackets of "in" is what it filters
             SELECT 'Class' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Mdn')                                            THEN 'Mdn'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Cl1', 'Cl2', 'Cl3')                              THEN 'Cl1,Cl2,Cl3'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Cl4', 'Cl5', 'Cl6')                              THEN 'Cl4,Cl5,Cl6'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('2yo')                                            THEN '2yo'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('3yo')                                            THEN '3yo'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Hcp', 'Hcap')                                    THEN 'Hcp'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Qlty', 'Listed', 'Grp3', 'Grp2', 'Grp1', 'WFA')  THEN 'Qlty,Listed,Grp3,Grp2,Grp1,WFA'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Days' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.DayNumber IN(1, 2, 3) THEN 'Sun-Mon-Tues'
                        WHEN td.DayNumber IN(4, 5)    THEN 'Wed-Sat'
                        WHEN td.DayNumber IN(6, 7)    THEN 'Thurs-Fri'
                    END AS label
         ) AS brackets 
         cross apply

          (
             SELECT 'All' AS category, 
                    'All' AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Runners' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.RaceRunners <= 7    THEN '01-07'
                        WHEN td.RaceRunners <= 12   THEN '07-12'
                        WHEN td.RaceRunners <= 1000 THEN '12-1000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Total Bracket Count' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.PriceBracketRunners = 1      THEN '01'
                        WHEN td.PriceBracketRunners IN(2, 3) THEN '02-03'
                        WHEN td.PriceBracketRunners > 3      THEN '04-1000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Distance' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.distance <= 1200  THEN '0-1200'
                        WHEN td.distance <= 1600  THEN '1200-1600'
                        WHEN td.distance <= 10000 THEN '1600-10000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Race' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.raceno < 5     THEN '0-4'
                        WHEN td.raceno < 1000  THEN '04-1000'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             --the stuff after the "then" is the title for the column, the stuff inside the brackets of "in" is what it filters
             SELECT 'Class' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Mdn')                                            THEN 'Mdn'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Cl1', 'Cl2', 'Cl3')                              THEN 'Cl1,Cl2,Cl3'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Cl4', 'Cl5', 'Cl6')                              THEN 'Cl4,Cl5,Cl6'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('2yo')                                            THEN '2yo'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('3yo')                                            THEN '3yo'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Hcp', 'Hcap')                                    THEN 'Hcp'
                        WHEN td.Class IN('Qlty', 'Listed', 'Grp3', 'Grp2', 'Grp1', 'WFA')  THEN 'Qlty,Listed,Grp3,Grp2,Grp1,WFA'
                    END AS label
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Days' AS category,
                    CASE
                        WHEN td.DayNumber IN(1, 2, 3) THEN 'Sun-Mon-Tues'
                        WHEN td.DayNumber IN(4, 5)    THEN 'Wed-Sat'
                        WHEN td.DayNumber IN(6, 7)    THEN 'Thurs-Fri'
                    END AS label
         ) AS brackets2
        -- where brackets.category  <> brackets2.category
         GROUP BY td.event_id, 
                  td.MENU_HINT, 
                  td.EVENT_NAME, 
                  td.Expr1003, 
                  td.RaceNo, 
                  td.Distance, 
                  td.Class, 
                  td.[Day], 
                  brackets.category, 
                  brackets2.category,
                  td.PriceBracketlabel, 
                  brackets.label,
                  brackets2.label),
     WinnerGroups
     AS (SELECT *, 
                SUM(CountHorses_Winners) OVER(PARTITION BY bracket_category, 
                                                           bracket_label
                ORDER BY Expr1003, 
                         RaceNo, 
                         event_id) AS winner_group_id, 
                SumPrices_Winners - CountHorses_Winners - CountHorses_Losers AS line_profit
         FROM DataCube),
     GroupTotals
     AS (SELECT bracket_category, 
                bracket_label, 
                winner_group_id, 
                SUM(line_profit) AS Group_Total_Profit
         FROM WinnerGroups
         GROUP BY bracket_category, 
                  bracket_label, 
                  winner_group_id),
     GroupSteppedTotals
     AS (SELECT bracket_category, 
                bracket_label, 
                winner_group_id, 
                Group_Total_Profit, 
                SUM(Group_Total_Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY bracket_category, 
                                                          bracket_label
                ORDER BY winner_group_id ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Group_Total1_Profit, 
                SUM(Group_Total_Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY bracket_category, 
                                                          bracket_label
                ORDER BY winner_group_id ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Group_Total2_Profit, 
                SUM(Group_Total_Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY bracket_category, 
                                                          bracket_label
                ORDER BY winner_group_id ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Group_Total3_Profit, 
                SUM(Group_Total_Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY bracket_category, 
                                                          bracket_label
                ORDER BY winner_group_id ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Group_Total5_Profit, 
                SUM(Group_Total_Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY bracket_category, 
                                                          bracket_label
                ORDER BY winner_group_id ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Group_Total8_Profit
         FROM GroupTotals),
     RunningTotals
     AS (SELECT *, 
                SUM(line_profit) OVER(PARTITION BY bracket_category, 
                                                   bracket_label, 
                                                   winner_group_id
                ORDER BY Expr1003 DESC, 
                         RaceNo DESC, 
                         event_id DESC) - line_profit AS Group_Partial_Profit
         FROM WinnerGroups),
     LaggedProfits
     AS (SELECT RunningTotals.*, 
                GroupSteppedTotals.Group_Total_Profit, 
                LAG(RunningTotals.winner_group_id) OVER(PARTITION BY RunningTotals.bracket_category, 
                                                                     RunningTotals.bracket_label
                ORDER BY RunningTotals.Expr1003, 
                         RunningTotals.RaceNo, 
                         RunningTotals.event_id) AS previous_winner_group_id, 
                (GroupSteppedTotals.Group_Total1_Profit - RunningTotals.Group_Partial_Profit) AS profit_back1winner, 
                (GroupSteppedTotals.Group_Total2_Profit - RunningTotals.Group_Partial_Profit) AS profit_back2winner, 
                (GroupSteppedTotals.Group_Total3_Profit - RunningTotals.Group_Partial_Profit) AS profit_back3winner, 
                (GroupSteppedTotals.Group_Total5_Profit - RunningTotals.Group_Partial_Profit) AS profit_back5winner, 
                (GroupSteppedTotals.Group_Total8_Profit - RunningTotals.Group_Partial_Profit) AS profit_back8winner
         FROM RunningTotals
              INNER JOIN GroupSteppedTotals ON GroupSteppedTotals.bracket_category = RunningTotals.bracket_category
                                               AND GroupSteppedTotals.bracket_label = RunningTotals.bracket_label
                                               AND GroupSteppedTotals.winner_group_id = RunningTotals.winner_group_id)
     SELECT
     event_id, 
     MENU_HINT, 
     EVENT_NAME, 
     Expr1003, 
     Class, 
     RaceNo, 
     bracket_category, 
     bracket_label, 
     --  winner_group_id, -- Debugging Column

     CountHorses_Winners, 
     SumPrices_Winners, 
     CountHorses_Losers, 
     SumPrices_Losers, 
     --  line_profit, -- Debugging Column
     --  Group_Partial_Profit, -- Debugging Column
     --  Group_Total_Profit, -- Debugging Column

     CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners > 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 1 THEN profit_back1winner END AS Profit_Winner_1,
     CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners > 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 2 THEN profit_back2winner END AS Profit_Winner_2,
     CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners > 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 3 THEN profit_back3winner END AS Profit_Winner_3,
     CASE WHEN (previous_winner_group_id >= 3 and CountHorses_Winners <> 0) THEN  cast(((profit_back1winner +  profit_back2winner +profit_back3winner)/3) as decimal(10,2)) END AS Average_Winner, 
     -- CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners > 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 5 THEN profit_back5winner END   AS Profit_Winner_5,
     -- CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners > 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 8 THEN profit_back8winner END   AS Profit_Winner_8,

     CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners = 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 1 AND CountHorses_Losers > 0 THEN profit_back1winner END AS Profit_NotWinner_1,
     CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners = 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 2 AND CountHorses_Losers > 0 THEN profit_back2winner END AS Profit_NotWinner_2,
     CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners = 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 3 AND CountHorses_Losers > 0 THEN profit_back3winner END AS Profit_NotWinner_3,
     CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners = 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 3 AND CountHorses_Losers > 0 THEN cast(((profit_back1winner +  profit_back2winner +profit_back3winner)/3) as decimal(10,2)) END AS Average_NotWinner
     -- CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners = 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 5 AND CountHorses_Losers > 0 THEN profit_back5winner END   AS Profit_NotWinner_5,
     -- CASE WHEN CountHorses_Winners = 0 AND previous_winner_group_id >= 8 AND CountHorses_Losers > 0 THEN profit_back8winner END   AS Profit_NotWinner_8
     FROM LaggedProfits


     WHERE bracket_category in ('All', 'Class', 'Days', 'Distance', 'Race', 'Runners', 'Total Bracket Count', 'Class : Days','Class : Distance','Class : Race', 'Class : Runners', 'Class : Total Bracket Count', 'Days : Distance', 'Days : Race', 'Days : Runners', 
                                'Days : Total Bracket Count', 'Distance : Race', 'Distance : Runners', 'Distance : Total Bracket Count', 'Race : Runners', 'Race : Total Bracket Count', 'Runners : Total Bracket Count')
                                --and bracket_label = '03-05 : All'
        -- WHERE --@Category IS NULL OR bracket_category IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Category, ',')) and
    --event_id = 145688261
     --AND LaggedProfits.MENU_HINT  LIKE '%MVal%'
     --bracket_category = 'Runners2'    AND 
  --  and  bracket_label = '03-05 : Hcp : Wed-Sat'
     --LaggedProfits.MENU_HINT LIKE '%Flem%'
     ORDER BY Expr1003 DESC, 
              RaceNo DESC, 
              event_id DESC, 
              bracket_category, 
              bracket_label, 
              Class;
```

Basically what I need is that information is retrieved for all combinations even when there is not, similar to a "isnull" I think  so when exported to excel there is headers for categories without combinations in the DB

Comment: You should show your whole statement.  What you have written is only part of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join`.  Something like this:

```
select v.label, count(td.bsp)
from (values (0, 2, '01-02'),
             (2, 2, '02-03'),
             . . .  -- continue with the remaining groups
     ) v(lo, hi, label) left join
     td
     on td.BSP > v.lo and td.BSP = v.hi
group by v.label
order by v.lo;
```

Comment: I've added the complete statement

Comment: to explain a little better, 
my dataset returns data for all combinations iterations of BSP, but only when it exists, I need to have printed with 0 the labels for all of them, so I can check when data doesn't exist as well for example https://i.imgur.com/tScR32y.png does not have Bracket_label 01-02 since no data exists, I want the 01-02 to appear with '0'

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as using an `ELSE` in your `CASE` statement?

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN td.BSP <= 2 THEN '01-02'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 3 THEN '02-03'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 5 THEN '03-05'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 8 THEN '05-08'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 13 THEN '08-13'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 21 THEN '13-21'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 34 THEN '21-34'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 55 THEN '34-55'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 89 THEN '55-89'
            WHEN td.BSP <= 1000 THEN '89-1000'
            ELSE '0'
       END AS label
```

Comment: not really, I want the line with 01-02' to appear in the report with that combination, right now if there are no numbers to operate in the bracket, the line doesn't appear, I want the end result to show a 0 for that bracket